# Scraping App Store returns irrelevant images

Tags: python, web-crawler, app-store

I am trying to scrape App Store pages of games to fetch their icon and screenshots using Python. However, sometimes it returns some random images that are not necessarily game screenshots. For example, it might return Apple Maps screenshot etc.

Here is my script to get image URLs,

```
def get_app_store_images_icon(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

    link = soup.find('ul', {"class": "l-row l-row--peek we-screenshot-viewer__screenshots-list"})
    
    link_icon = soup.find('div', {"class": "product-hero__media l-column small-5 medium-4 large-3 small-valign-top"})
    images = []
    try:
         for subHtml in link.find_all('picture'):
            image_sources = subHtml.find_all('source')[-1].get('srcset')
            # to get last image in srcset
            start = image_sources.rindex(", ")
            end = image_sources.rindex(" ")
            images.append(image_sources[start+2:end])

    except:
        return None
    try:
        image_icon_sources = link_icon.find_all('source')[-1].get('srcset')
        start = image_icon_sources.rindex(", ")
        end = image_icon_sources.rindex(" ")
        image_icon = image_icon_sources[start+2:end]
    except:
        return None
    
    all_images = {'images': images, 'icon': image_icon}
    return all_images
```

I am using `BeautifulSoup4 version 4.9.1` and `Python 3.7`

I want to know if this is a bug or Apple's security conventions to dynamically change images for crawlers.

Comment: Most likely your crawler is just finding images you didn't want it to.

Comment: if they have an API, you should use that instead of scraping btw

Comment: @user253751 but there is no such image urls when I inspect source html on Chrome

Comment: @HarunSasmaz perhaps they are "recommended apps" or something like that - does part of the page change each time you refresh it?

Comment: @Matiiss unfortunately not

Comment: @user253751 but sometimes I get images that are not even games or apps

Comment: Is Apple Maps not an app?

Comment: @user253751 apple maps will never be a recommendation for a mobile game